# IE8 disabled element text rendering differences

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Below is a super zoomed in image of a disabled `<select>` element (top), and a disabled `<textarea>` element with it's text highlighted for more emphasis on the issue (bottom), both being rendered by the god-awful IE8.

[image]

I've disabled all styles in various dev tools, overridden `color`, `text-shadow` `font-family` etc...

Why do `<textarea>` and other  `<input [type='*']>` elements render with some goofy text highlighting, while `<select>` elements render without it, and even more importantly is there a workaround to get rid of that text highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE adds it's own styles and while you can control background and font colors, something like

```
 input[type="*"]:disabled {
   background-color: none;
   color: gray;
 }
```

you cannot remove shadows. One alternative -  don't set actual DISABLED attribute, but simulate it instead e.g use readonly attribute, set `onfocus = "this.blur()"` etc.

Comment: simple, and works pretty decent. you still have to set the disable attribute on the select elements but for everything else i just created my own .disabled class and added a pretty simple jq event onfocus event for all .disabled elements.